# Non-uniform `shift`ing: leads/lags with multiple within-period&ID observations

Tags: r, data.table

The use of `shift` is well-documented as a way to get lead and lag values of variables, but I'm struggling with extending this logic to a situation where I have multiple observations within each period for some or all IDs.

Example:

```
dt<-data.table(id=rep(1:2,c(6,3)),
               pd=rep(rep(1:3,2),c(1:3,1,1,1)),
               firm=c(rep(c("01","02"),c(4,2)),
                      c("04","05","06")))
```

The basic approach is wrong:

```
dt[,paste0("firm_",c("lag","lead")):=
 .(shift(firm),shift(firm,type="lead")),by=id]
> dt
   id pd firm firm_lag firm_lead
1:  1  1   01       NA        01
2:  1  2   01       01        01
3:  1  2   01       01        01
4:  1  3   01       01        02 #all lags should be 01 for id 1 in pd 3
5:  1  3   02       01        02 #all leads should be NA for id 1 in pd 3
6:  1  3   02       02        NA
7:  2  1   04       NA        05
8:  2  2   05       04        06
9:  2  3   06       05        NA
```

My current workaround is to do a self-merge:

```
dt[setkey(unique(dt)[,.(pd,shift(firm),shift(firm,type="lead")),by=id],id,pd),
   c("lag","lead"):=.(i.V2,i.V3)]
> dt
   id pd firm lag lead
1:  1  1   01  NA   01
2:  1  2   01  01   01
3:  1  2   01  01   01
4:  1  3   01  01   NA
5:  1  3   02  01   NA
6:  1  3   02  01   NA
7:  2  1   04  NA   05
8:  2  2   05  04   06
9:  2  3   06  05   NA
```

This is correct, but it is quite messy. Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: What happens if you have multiple id/pd combos that have different values of firm?  If that never happens then why would you have two rows that have the exact same data?

Comment: @DeanMacGregor My guess is that firm is uniquely identified by those cols, but there are some other cols (not shown here) that vary in a meaningful way.

Comment: @Frank I guess I'm just dense because even if those other columns are there, does that make them part of an index?  MichaelChirico, if that's the case *maybe* you could dcast from long to wide before lag/lead and then if you want melt again.  I don't have a feel on whether or not that is better/worse than merging though.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Not sure what you mean by an index, but yeah, I would structure my data differently to avoid redundant info. The question is interesting, but I think it would've been better with plain old `data.table(pd=c(1,2,2,3,3,3))` as its example. The other stuff is a distraction.

Comment: @Frank like a SQL primary key constraint.

Comment: @eddi thanks, that'll make it cleaner; I'm still a bit averse to `on` until I figure out what's slowing it down (see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1232); this is being done on the same data set)

Comment: @DeanMacGregor Not exactly in my real data, but I didn't want to over-complicate this. It _is_ often the case that `firm` is unique in the previous period, but that other variables vary meaningfully as @Frank said. `dcast`ing is probably to be avoided--3m observations of 90 variables would become 2.5 m observations... of 2790 variables. ew.

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way without merging:

```
dt[,c("lag","lead"):={
  r <- rleid(pd)
  x <- .SD[,firm[1],by=pd]$V1
  lapply(c("lag","lead"), function(y) x[shift(r,type=y)] )
}, by=id]
```

As far as performance goes, there are probably faster ways than the `.SD` line. I would try `ave(firm,pd,FUN=function(x)x[1])`, for example.